# Internet on windows but not on linux

Tags: linux, internet

We are using Asus rx3041 router to access the internet, and it's configured to use 192.168.13.* and it's set to 192.168.13.1. It's acting as a gateway and dhcp server, with default configuration.

Since the router has been reset or something else has been done, the internet access in linux (slackware 13.37 x64) is no longer working.

On Win7 and on Linux it gets the same IP address, the same options, the same dns/dhcp server but still on linux there is no access to the internet.

When I ping something it returns destination unreachable. I don't know what else to do.

Please help me if someone has had similar problem or knows how to solve this.

---

I just started a Windows 7 virtual machine in Linux and as you can see, there's Internet access here too. And  Yes, it does ping the 192.168.13.1 and I have no rules in iptables or something like that.

EDIT: I've reset the router back to factory settings, and now there is an access to Internet from Linux. I'm just curios why even from Windows 7 virtual machine on the same network there was Internet access and with the same options on Linux - not? .

Comment: Does pinging the router itself produce an unreachable `ping 192.168.13.1` from linux?  If you ping google.com does it resolve to an IP address?  Is the connection wired or wireless?  Do you know the speed of the ports on the router if wired (100mb or 1GB)?

Comment: Please register on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I have witnessed a situation when a dual-boot computer wouldn't get an IP over DHCP from router after rebooting it from Windows (XP) to Linux (incidentally, Slackware 13.37). I tend to think it was a combination of Windows behaving incorrectly and of a big timeout on router's DHCP server - I've managed to discover by trial and error that if I manually release the IP in Windows via **ipconfig /release** just before rebooting it - Linux would get the IP after reboot.